# Acumatica Manufacturing error on publishing

Tags: c#, sql, database, acumatica

I suddenly encountered an error in my manufacturing edition and it came out of nowhere so this is the error that I have.

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.SYProviderField' with unique index 'SYProviderField_UK'. The duplicate key value is (3, f7761087-6293-4dbe-b4d9-81feaf4a6f12, Data, 31).
The statement has been terminated.
```

this error just suddenly showed on the publishing of the customization project of the JAMS manufacturing edition I cant figure out if what i will do with it i tried using another Manufacturing customization but still no luck.

Comment: Never heard of JAMS or Acumatica. But you did read the error message? One key in your publishing project is used twice, hence not unique.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to pop up randomly. The key points to the import provider

```
ProviderID="f7761087-6293-4dbe-b4d9-81feaf4a6f12" Name="Import BOM 2018R2"
```

Remove the import "Import BOM 2018R2" from the manufacturing customization and try to publish again